# How to toggle open & close menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a slide menu but I don't know how would I close it back.

Basically i'm trying to do something like this website https://zero.nyc/

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('aside');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.style.marginLeft = '0';
  menu.style.left = '97vw';
})
```

```css
aside {
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav {
  width: 97vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -100vw;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  menu
</aside>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Put the styles you're setting in JS into a CSS class, then toggle the class on/off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css classes and toggle them on or off on in your click method instead of setting the styles through javascript.

Snippet:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('aside');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle("margin");
  menu.classList.toggle("left");
})
```

```css
aside {
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
}

nav {
  width: 97vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -100vw;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
}

.margin {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 97vw;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  menu
</aside>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you guyz, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I would create css classes to toggle within your click event handler instead of manually changing the styles.

On click you're basically going to:

1. Grab the elements you want to change
2. Toggle the classes using classList.toggle (if you're not worried about < ie9)

Benefit of using classes is once you remove it, the element simply reverts. It's also more maintainable because you don't have to keep track of the styles you change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: translateX()` instead of margin. You also have to write some state of your menu i.e. opened/closed. You can use a css class for that, and in your eventListener you can check if menu is `opened`, then onClick animate from `translateX(0)` to `translateX(-100%)`and remove `opened` class.

Or you can write styles with transitions, or @keyframes animations, everything will work. Just build the idea of storing opened state first.